# How to attach docs and import issue at the same time using GitHub API?

Tags: github, curl, github-api

I need to import all bug reports and attachments from my internal system to GitHub Issues.

What GitHub API parameter should I use to attach a document in my curl command?

```
curl -X "POST" \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
               -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.html" \
     -H "Authorization: token <token>" \
               https://api.github.com/repos/BT23/demo-repo/issues \
               -d '{
               "title":"Create an issue in HTML format",
               "body":"<H1>Testing HTML tags</H1><P>Does it work?</P>",
               "assignee": "BT23",
               "milestone": 1,
               "labels":["bug", "functional"]
               }'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the word file anywhere in [Issues API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues).

And [this thread](https://github.community/t/attach-a-file-during-issue-creation/141381) confirms you cannot attach a file during Issue Creation.

Adding a file to issue or pull request seems to be done [manually through drag & drop only](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/attaching-files).

Comment: If I upload documents to repository contents, can I link the file to the issue?

Comment: @BAST23 Not through [GitHub API v3 (create an issue)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues#create-an-issue). Maybe through GraphQL API v4 (and [`ProjectV2ItemConnection`](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#projectv2itemconnection)), but I don't know how. It has been introduced fairly recently (June 2022), with ["new ProjectV2 object to our GraphQL API "](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-06-23-the-new-github-issues-june-23rd-update/).